# Black screen after suspend on 17.10

Tags: 17.10, suspend, intel-graphics

A little while ago I started getting a black screen when resuming my computer from sleep. Suspension has been working fine for months but all of a sudden my computer gets completely unresponsive. I can't even switch to another tty. After a hard shutdown everything works fine, but the same behavior reappears after every suspend (`systemctl suspend`). It actually looks like the screen doesn't turn on at all. It's not just blank but completely black.

I've checked boot.log, syslog and the systemd logs and I can't find anything that looks like any serious problem.

My computer is a Thinkpad Carbon X1 (with an Intel graphics card) and runs the mini.iso release of Ubuntu 17.10. I tried updating my kernel to `4.15.0` but no change. I even tried reinstalling my entire system (including not using Luks-encryption for my home directory) still no change. Now I'm back to the standard kernel version (`4.13.0`)

I'm really stumped here an have no idea where to look right now. I'd really appreciate some help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by removing `nomodeset` from the `GRUB_CMD_LINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable in `/etc/default/grub` and then running `update-grub`. I'm not sure why this change made any difference but apparently it doesn't work for me any more.